# Get an instance of a class by its name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0

I have StrategyName set in appsettings.json which represents the name of the strategy class. I need to get an instance of it.

```cs
ITradingStrategy _tradingStrategy = StrategyUtils.GetStrategyInstance(logger, _tradeOptions.StrategyName)
```

which is equal to

```cs
ITradingStrategy _tradingStrategy = new RsiStrategy(logger);
```

Is it possible to be made in a better way? It works but looks ugly. Since we know the strategy name in the beginning (from appsettings.json), there should probably be a way to obtain it in a better ASP.NET Core way. Maybe some cool extension method, I don't know.

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  "TradeConfiguration": {
    "StrategyName": "RsiStrategy",
    ...
  }
}
```

#### Code

```cs
public class LiveTradeManager : ITradeManager
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IExchangeClient _exchangeClient;
    private readonly ITradingStrategy _tradingStrategy;
    private readonly ExchangeOptions _exchangeOptions;
    private readonly TradeOptions _tradeOptions;

    public LiveTradeManager(ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration, IExchangeClient exchangeClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _exchangeClient = exchangeClient;
        _exchangeOptions = configuration.GetSection("ExchangeConfiguration").Get<ExchangeOptions>();
        _tradeOptions = configuration.GetSection("TradeConfiguration").Get<TradeOptions>();
        _tradingStrategy = StrategyUtils.GetStrategyInstance(logger, _tradeOptions.StrategyName); // This is the questioned line
    }
}

public static ITradingStrategy GetStrategyInstance(ILogger logger, string strategyName)
{
    var strategyType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(StrategyBase))
        .GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(StrategyBase)) && type.Name.Equals(strategyName));

    if (strategyType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The strategy \"{strategyName}\" could not be found.", nameof(strategyName));
    }

    var strategy = Activator.CreateInstance(strategyType, logger) as ITradingStrategy;

    return strategy;
}

// Strategies
public interface ITradingStrategy
{
    IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Prepare(IReadOnlyList<OHLCV> candles);
}

public abstract class StrategyBase : ITradingStrategy
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    protected StrategyBase(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public abstract IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Prepare(IReadOnlyList<OHLCV> candles);
}

public class RsiStrategy : StrategyBase
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RsiStrategy(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public override IReadOnlyList<TradeAdvice> Prepare(IReadOnlyList<OHLCV> candles)
    {
        ... _logger.Information("Test");
    }
}

// Main
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton(
                    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                        .CreateLogger());

                services.AddSingleton<ITradeManager, LiveTradeManager>();
                services.AddSingleton<IExchangeClient, BinanceSpotClient>();
                
                services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();
            })
            .UseSerilog();
}
```

Comment: StrategyUtils.GetStrategyInstance should use ServiceCollection to resolve the type from DI.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, how could I do that by strategy name from appsettings.json?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, keep in mind that I also want to check whether it is a subclass type of `StrategyBase`.

Comment: Do you have any other class which is implementing `ITradingStrategy` interface but not inheriting from `StrategyBase` class? In future will there be other classes created implementing `ITradingStrategy` interface?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, no. StrategyBase is the only base class of the strategies and ITradingStrategy is its interface.

Comment: You will have only one Strategy, `RsiStrategy` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, no there are multiple of them. RsiStrategy, DmiStrategy, MacdStrategy, etc. They inherit from StrategyBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved multiple ways and using reflection would be the last one.

From your problem statement, I figure that you have multiple strategy classed implementing `ITradingStrategy` interface, and you configuration value from `appsettings.json` file decides which strategy to use.

One of the approach you can use here is to use factory to initialize appropriate strategy class based on the configuration value.

Following is the factory class and interface which will create Strategy class object based on the strategy name passed to it.

```
public interface IStrategyFactory
{
    ITradingStrategy GetStrategy(string strategyName);
}

public class StrategyFactory : IStrategyFactory
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public StrategyFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    }
    public ITradingStrategy GetStrategy(string strategyName)
    {
        switch (strategyName)
        {
            case "Rsi":
                // Resolve RsiStrategy object from the serviceProvider.
                return _serviceProvider.GetService<RsiStrategy>();
            case "Dmi":
                // Resolve DmiStrategy object from the serviceProvider.
                return _serviceProvider.GetService<DmiStrategy>();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This strategy can now be used in controller and call its `GetStrategy` method by passing the strategy name which in-turn is retrieved from the configuration.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    // Strategy factory.
    private IStrategyFactory _strategyFactory;
    // Configuration
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IStrategyFactory strategyFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _strategyFactory = strategyFactory;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Get Configuration value "StrategyName" from configuration.
        // In your case this will be your own custom configuration.
        var strategyName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("StrategyName");

        // Pass strategyName to GetStrategy Method.
        var strategy = _strategyFactory.GetStrategy(strategyName);

        // Call Prepare method on the retrieved strategy object.
        ViewBag.PreparedList = strategy.Prepare(new List<OHLCV>());
        return View();
    }
}
```

For the above code to work you need to register strategy classed in to serviceCollection.

```
services.AddSingleton<RsiStrategy>();
services.AddSingleton<DmiStrategy>();
```

And also the StrategyFactory.

```
services.AddSingleton<IStrategyFactory, StrategyFactory>();
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, you need to be able to resolve the strategy types without additional overhead of registering them in DI as when new types are created and also without making changes in the factory.

You need to use reflection for this. Using reflection you can determine the types which you want to register in the DI. As following.

```
//Get all the types which are inheriting from StrategyBase class from the assembly.
var strategyTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(StrategyBase))
    ?.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(StrategyBase)));

if (strategyTypes != null)
{
    //Loop thru the types collection and register them in serviceCollection.
    foreach (var type in strategyTypes)
    {
        services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(StrategyBase), type, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
    }
}
```

With the above code, all the types which are inheriting from StrategyBase are registered in serviceCollection. Now using serivceProvider we can get all the registered instances and look for the instance which has correct strategyName.

So the factory's GetStrategy method will look like as following.

```
public ITradingStrategy GetStrategy(string strategyName)
{
    var strategies = _serviceProvider.GetServices<StrategyBase>();

    var strategy = strategies.FirstOrDefault(s => s.GetType().Name == strategyName);

    if (strategy == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The strategy \"{strategyName}\" could not be found.", nameof(strategyName));
    }

    return strategy;
}
```

I hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can it somehow identify the strategies by itself, just by looking at what inherits StrategyBase? It's an overhead for the user when he creates a new strategy file to be adding it as a singleton or in the factory method. `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`?

Comment: I updated my answer to include solution for your requirement.